# Python 2.7 - Elasticsearch - SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3'

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode

I am using elasticsearch with python 2.7. I have to analyze and store a lot of text; often appears the following error: 
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character ... 
I wrote the following code for testing:

```
 import elasticsearch

 es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch("127.0.0.1:9200")
 test = 'sarà'
 doc = {
 'ID':'123456',
 'field':unicode(test, errors='ignore'),
  }
 es.index('test_db','test',doc)
```

The error is:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /home/user/PycharmProjects/ubuntu/asciiTest.py on line 4, but no encoding declared.

After reading other answer on stackoverflow I tried:

```
unicode(test, errors='ignore')
```

But again the same error. I don't know how to manage these special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is telling you that you're used non-ASCII characters but haven't declared the formating of the source code.

The error is usually accompanied by a message referring you to  PEP-263 - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

You can simply add the following to the top of your source code:

```
# coding=<encoding name>
```

`<encoding name>` is the encoding you've used for the source code. It's advisable to use utf-8.

When using non-ASCII, you ought to use Unicode strings. You can achieve this by simply appending a `u` in front of the string value.

E.g.

```
test = u'sarà'
```

Remove all uses of `unicode()`. IMHO, `unicode()` should never been used without an encoding given